# Vue 3 Render function event listener not working

Tags: vue.js, events, render

I'm using the  render : () => functionality to create html nodes , everything works as expeted. However when i'm trying to set a event listener on a button, the function doesn't trigger.

The onClick event can be found in the pagination controls below .

the console.log in the changePange function never triggers, i also get no errors in the console.

Does somebody know what is wrong here ?

```
import { createApp, h, ref } from "vue";
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";

export function createInfoBubble(args, pageNumber = 1) {
  const itemsPerPage = 1;
  const startIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage;
  const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
  console.log(startIndex, endIndex);
  function changePage(newPageNumber) {
    // Ensure the new page number is within valid range
    console.log("paginate");
    if (
      newPageNumber >= 1 &&
      newPageNumber <= Math.ceil(args.length / itemsPerPage)
    ) {
      app.unmount(); // Unmount the current instance
      createInfoBubble(args, newPageNumber); // Create new instance with new page number
    }
  }
  const app = createApp({
    render: () =>
      h("div", { class: "w-[400px] flex flex-col gap-y-3" }, [
        args.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((item, index) => {
          return h("div", { class: "border-b border-primary ", key: index }, [
            h(
              "h3",
              { class: "text-primary" },
              `Location ${item.data[0].location.name}`
            ),
            h(
              "div",
              { class: "flex gap-x-2" },
              `${item.data[0].location.street}, ${item.data[0].location.zip}  ${item.data[0].location.city} ${item.data[0].location.country_code}`
            ),
            h("div", { class: "flex flex-col mt-2" }, [
              h("h4", { class: "font-bold" }, "Coordinates"),
              h("div", { class: "mt-1 flex gap-x-2" }, [
                h("p", `Lat: ${item.data[0].location.lat}`),
                h("p", `Lng: ${item.data[0].location.lng}`),
              ]),
            ]),
            h("div", { class: "flex flex-col mt-2" }, [
              h("div", { class: "flex flex-wrap" }, [
                ...item.data[1].chargepoint.map((chargepoint, index) => {
                  return h("div", { class: "flex-item mt-2 ", key: index }, [
                    h("div", { class: "flex flex-wrap" }, [
                      h(
                        Link,
                        {
                          class: "text-primary hover:opacity-50",
                          href: route(
                            "chargepoints.details.show",
                            chargepoint.id
                          ),
                        },
                        chargepoint.code
                      ),
                      h(
                        "span",
                        `Available: ${chargepoint.connectors.available}`
                      ),
                      h(
                        "span",
                        `Unavailable: ${chargepoint.connectors.unavailable}`
                      ),
                      h("span", `Charging: ${chargepoint.connectors.charging}`),
                    ]),
                  ]);
                }),
              ]),
            ]),
          ]);
        }),

        // Pagination controls
        h(
          "div",
          {
            class:
              "flex mt-2 gap-x-2 justify-between bg-primary text-white px-4 rounded-sm",
          },
          [
            h(
              "button",
              { onClick: () => changePage(pageNumber - 1) },
              "Previous"
            ),
            h("span", `Page ${pageNumber}`),
            h("button", { onClick: () => changePage(pageNumber + 1) }, "Next"),
          ]
        ),
      ]),
  });

  const vm = app.mount(document.createElement("div"));
  return vm.$el.outerHTML;
}
```

I have tried directly placing the console.log() inside the h() itself. This also fails with no errors

```
h(
  "button",
  { onClick: () => console.log('paginate') },
  "Previous"
),
```

Comment: This `vm.$el.outerHTML`. You use Vue as template engine and disable all the reactivity. This is likely XY problem and there's a better way for what you're trying to do

Comment: Well first of thanks for the comment ! But i need to import a template or component with dynamic data for a here maps info bubble, since the here maps only accepts html i was trying to generate it via the render function.

Is there a way to achieve what i want using the render () function ?

Comment: It's natural for third-party apis to accept an element instead of static html for the cases like yours, otherwise this would limit their usage, this occurs in some old libs but Here is popular one and up-to-date, so yes, it's solved like you did

Answer (score 1):

Update: as per Estus Flask's comment I have got the desired result.

**outerHTML disables reactivity**

I have done following changes to my code

1. Made the pageNuber a ref()
2. adjusted the slice & pagination controls for the pageNumber ref
3. return vm.$el instead of vm.$el.outerHTML

   ```js
   export function createInfoBubble(args, pageNumber = 1) {
     const itemsPerPage = 1;
     const currentPageNumber = ref(pageNumber);

     function changePage(newPageNumber) {
       if (
         newPageNumber >= 1 &&
         newPageNumber <= Math.ceil(args.length / itemsPerPage)
       ) {
         currentPageNumber.value = newPageNumber;
       }
     }
   ...

    args
         .slice(
           (currentPageNumber.value - 1) * itemsPerPage,
           currentPageNumber.value * itemsPerPage
         )
         .map((item, index) => {
   ...
   { onClick: () => changePage(currentPageNumber.value + 1) },
   ..
    return vm.$el;
   ```